# Where to include Parse initialization keys in my Meteor App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, parse-platform

I want to use Parse as my back-end for a Meteor application, and I have added the jquery & parse-sdk packages from Atmosphere to my application, but I am not sure in which directory/file to place the Parse initialization keys.

Currently I have two files,  client/main.html and client/main.js, and have attempted placing my keys inside and outside the template helper in client/main.js , as well as in their own file in the /lib directory, but nothing worked.

Should I be placing the keys in some other, globally available location perhaps? When I try to run the app the locally, I receive the following error message:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/main.js:4:8: Unexpected token .

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

And this is the beginning of my main.js file:

```
 1 
 2 Template.user_loggedOut.helpers({
 3 
 4 Parse.initialize(" my-app-ID", "my-js-id");
 5 
 6 // Parse.$ = jQuery; commented out to focus on first error, possibly unnecessary w/ jquery        package
 7 
 8 var LogInView = Parse.View.extend({
 9 events: {
```

I am new to both Parse & Meteor, so it is very likely I am overlooking something simple. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your `main.js` file is invalid JavaScript. The `helpers()` method takes an object (a `{"key": value}` hash). Other than that, all I can say is trying to incorporate these two frameworks is going to be very difficult. There seems to be a lot of overlap in what they do, but with completely different ideologies. Meteor is a full-stack framework; it is both a back end and a front end. It's a lot easier to replace the front end part than the back end, though even that is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

See [Meteor-Parse package](https://github.com/jcastelli/meteor-parse-sdk) which basically adds Parse JS SDK as Meteor package.

Answer (score 0):

if you call `Session.get('currentList')` from inside a template, the template will automatically be rendered whenever `Session.set('currentList', x)` is called.

To add Session to your application:

```sh
$ meteor add session
```

e.g:

```js
import { Session } from 'meteor/session'
Session.set(key, value)
```

---

`Session.set` can also be called with an object of keys and values, which is equivalent to calling `Session.set` individually on each key/value pair.